# Magento 2 : Shopping cart is empty but Display product in mini cart

Tags: magento2, checkout, mini-cart

I have work in Local Environment.
I had install multiple Magento version in my local environment.
I have two Magento project of version 2.3.0 and 2.3.1.
When I had Add one product in Mage231 project and I had run Mage230 project
then Mage230 will display product in mini cart with same options and same Name.
and when i will goto Checkout page it will display Me...

[image: mini cart image]

and Mage231 will work Properly.

[image: mage231 mini cart]

What is Main issue..